# Calling a VBA sub with arguments gives a syntax error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following variables in use in a set of subs:

```
Public WeightCap As Double  ' Weight capacity
Public HeightCap As Double  ' Height capacity
Public WeightRunning As Double  ' Weight running total
Public HeightRunning As Double  ' Height running total
Public WeightRunningCheck As Double  ' Weight running total for check
Public HeightRunningCheck As Double  ' Height running total for check
```

With these, I'm trying to call the RTFiller sub as follows:

```
HeightRunningCheck = HeightRunning + wsStacker.Cells(iSrcCountLine + 1, 12).Value
WeightRunningCheck = WeightRunning + wsStacker.Cells(iSrcCountLine + 1, 13).Value
RTFiller(HeightRunningCheck, WeightRunningCheck)
```

The RTFiller sub is defined thus:

```
Private Sub RTFiller(HeightTot As Double, WeightTot As Double)
```

However, trying to run it prompts a syntax error on the `RTFiller(HeightRunningCheck, WeightRunningCheck)`line, and when I try to debug it I get "Compile error: Expected: ="

I must have forgotten something obvious and vital, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either use:

```
Call RTFiller(HeightRunningCheck, WeightRunningCheck)
```

or:

```
RTFiller HeightRunningCheck, WeightRunningCheck
```

Unless you use Call, or are returning a value from a function (or are specifically trying to dereference/evaluate one of the parameters) you don't use parentheses.